# Kendo scheduler showing days in middle of square in IE 8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, kendo-ui

The Kendo scheduler is showing the dates in the middle of the date cell.  This only happens in IE 8.  All other versions of IE, Chrome, and FF show it correctly at the top of the cell.  Is there some way to get the date to show correctly in IE 8?

[image]

heres the Html for generating the grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<CalendarViewModel>()
            .Name("scheduler")
            .Date(new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day))
            .StartTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 07, 00, 00))
            .EndTime(new DateTime(2013, 6, 13, 23, 00, 00))
            .Editable(false)
            .Height(900)
            .Events(e => e.DataBound("loadPersonnelTotals"))
                .EventTemplate(
                                "<div style='font-size:8pt;'>#= kendo.toString(title) # - #= kendo.toString(start, 'HH:mm') # - #= kendo.toString(end, 'HH:mm') # (#= kendo.toString(TotalPersonnel) #)</div>"
                )
            .Views(views =>
            {
                views.DayView();
                views.MonthView(month => month.Selected(true).DayTemplate("<div id='DayClass' style='float:left;'><span class='theDate'>#= kendo.toString(date, 'dd')#</span> <span class='PersonnelDayCount'/></div>"));
                views.AgendaView(a =>a.Title("Event List"));
            })
            .DataSource(d => d
            .Model(m => m.Id(f => f.Id))
            .Read("GetSchedule", "Home")
            )
      )
```

I've taken out the Events templates and the monthview template and it still renders the same way.

**UPDATE**

I ended up fixing it by adding a jquery method to vertically align the td to the top:

```
$("td").each(function () {
            $(this).css("vertical-align", "top");
        });
```

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML? also can you confirm that your page is served up with a valid doctype and the page/site is rendering in non-compatibility mode?

Comment: The html is just putting a scheduler on the page, nothing to it.  What should the doctype be.  I have the browser being forced to IE8:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>

Comment: ok so the page is running in "IE8" standards mode... but what HTML/CSS is being generated to render the calendar? (e.g. there is no such HTML element as a calendar, it is all done with divs, tables, etc. as needed.)

Comment: Can you add the generated HTML tags? the browser only knows about the generated HTML and CSS and thus without seeing that we can't determine what isn't working.